# CSS Selector Targeting

Tags: css, target

I'm trying to target a particular `<th>` within the table below and only that particular `<th>`

The `<th>` in question is the `<th>Abilities</th>` under located after the `<th>Weapons</th>`

There will be multiple of these in the larger dataset but being able to target in this smaller set of data would be ideal test.

I know `:nth-child`, `:nth-of-type` aren't able to help here due to their selector limitations, but is there a way to do so at all?

I'm very much a novice coder and this code is an output from an app with zero support from the developer anymore so highly unlikely the core coding design will ever change.

I also using an external stylesheet which I'd hope the code if there is any would sit in there.

```html
<table cellspacing="-1">
  <tr>
    <th>Psyker</th>
    <th>Cast</th>
    <th>Deny</th>
    <th>Powers Known</th>
    <th>Other</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="profile-name">Primaris Librarian</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>Smite, 2 Librarius</td>
    <td>-</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<table cellspacing="-1">
  <tr>
    <th>Unit</th>
    <th>M</th>
    <th>WS</th>
    <th>BS</th>
    <th>S</th>
    <th>T</th>
    <th>W</th>
    <th>A</th>
    <th>Ld</th>
    <th>Save</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="profile-name">Primaris Librarian</td>
    <td>6"</td>
    <td>3+</td>
    <td>3+</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>9</td>
    <td>3+</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<table cellspacing="-1">
  <tr>
    <th>Weapon</th>
    <th>Range</th>
    <th>Type</th>
    <th>S</th>
    <th>AP</th>
    <th>D</th>
    <th>Abilities</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="profile-name">Bolt pistol</td>
    <td>12"</td>
    <td>Pistol 1</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>-</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="profile-name">Force sword</td>
    <td>Melee</td>
    <td>Melee</td>
    <td>+1</td>
    <td>-3</td>
    <td>D3</td>
    <td>-</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="profile-name">Frag grenades</td>
    <td>6"</td>
    <td>Grenade D6</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>Blast.</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="profile-name">Krak grenades</td>
    <td>6"</td>
    <td>Grenade 1</td>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>-1</td>
    <td>D3</td>
    <td>-</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Please take the time to format your code better. E.g get rid of all that white space to the left. Make it as easy as possible for us to help you

Comment: apologies, was the format the app exported it as.

Answer (score 0):

If you're able to add html to the existing table structure the easiest thing to do would be to put a class on the `<th>` that your trying to target. `<th class="abilities">Abilities</th>`

With the class added you can then apply styles to that class and they will apply only to any element in the table that you have assigned that class name to.

Then adding this class with the styles you want to your css sheet should do the trick.

```
.abilities {
   custom css styles here!
}
```

EDIT

Because you cant add styles directly to the existing HTML structure you could use Javascript or jQuery to crawl the page contents and find the word "Abilities" the code for that might look something like this

```
jQuery('th:contains("Abilities")').addClass('customClassName');
```

There might be some playing around needed to get it functioning exactly the way you want but this could be an option

the [:has()](https://api.jquery.com/has-selector/) Selector might also be usefull

Comment: I can't add any code to the original due to it being an export and i'd have to add this in manually between 1 and infinite times depending how long the "Army Roster" is configured too.

can this be pushed off to a external style sheet?

Comment: Not sure if you get notified of edits but I added a possible solution that would likely need some tinkering to get it functioning but it could be a good place to start!

Comment: I do see the notifications thanks, though I don't know where or how to implement JS or Jq only a novice coder.

Comment: adding scripts to a web application is a very similar process as adding your custom style sheets, usually in the head of your document you link to the path where your custom scripts sheets are located (commonly near the path of the css sheet)

Answer (score 0):

Easy to achieve in your example HTML, with the help of some pseudo selectors:

```css
table:nth-of-type(3) tr:first-of-type :last-child { color: red; }
```

```html
<table cellspacing="-1">
  <tr>
    <th>Psyker</th>
    <th>Cast</th>
    <th>Deny</th>
    <th>Powers Known</th>
    <th>Other</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="profile-name">Primaris Librarian</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>Smite, 2 Librarius</td>
    <td>-</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<table cellspacing="-1">
  <tr>
    <th>Unit</th>
    <th>M</th>
    <th>WS</th>
    <th>BS</th>
    <th>S</th>
    <th>T</th>
    <th>W</th>
    <th>A</th>
    <th>Ld</th>
    <th>Save</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="profile-name">Primaris Librarian</td>
    <td>6"</td>
    <td>3+</td>
    <td>3+</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>9</td>
    <td>3+</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<table cellspacing="-1">
  <tr>
    <th>Weapon</th>
    <th>Range</th>
    <th>Type</th>
    <th>S</th>
    <th>AP</th>
    <th>D</th>
    <th>Abilities</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="profile-name">Bolt pistol</td>
    <td>12"</td>
    <td>Pistol 1</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>-</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="profile-name">Force sword</td>
    <td>Melee</td>
    <td>Melee</td>
    <td>+1</td>
    <td>-3</td>
    <td>D3</td>
    <td>-</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="profile-name">Frag grenades</td>
    <td>6"</td>
    <td>Grenade D6</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>Blast.</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="profile-name">Krak grenades</td>
    <td>6"</td>
    <td>Grenade 1</td>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>-1</td>
    <td>D3</td>
    <td>-</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

If, due to the dynamic nature of the HTML, using pseudo selectors won't work for you, there sadly is no other way of achieving this other than adding a class, or resorting to JS:

```js
[...document.querySelectorAll('th')].find(th => th.textContent === 'Abilities').style.color = 'red';
```

```html
<table cellspacing="-1">
  <tr>
    <th>Psyker</th>
    <th>Cast</th>
    <th>Deny</th>
    <th>Powers Known</th>
    <th>Other</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="profile-name">Primaris Librarian</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>Smite, 2 Librarius</td>
    <td>-</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<table cellspacing="-1">
  <tr>
    <th>Unit</th>
    <th>M</th>
    <th>WS</th>
    <th>BS</th>
    <th>S</th>
    <th>T</th>
    <th>W</th>
    <th>A</th>
    <th>Ld</th>
    <th>Save</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="profile-name">Primaris Librarian</td>
    <td>6"</td>
    <td>3+</td>
    <td>3+</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>9</td>
    <td>3+</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<table cellspacing="-1">
  <tr>
    <th>Weapon</th>
    <th>Range</th>
    <th>Type</th>
    <th>S</th>
    <th>AP</th>
    <th>D</th>
    <th>Abilities</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="profile-name">Bolt pistol</td>
    <td>12"</td>
    <td>Pistol 1</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>-</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="profile-name">Force sword</td>
    <td>Melee</td>
    <td>Melee</td>
    <td>+1</td>
    <td>-3</td>
    <td>D3</td>
    <td>-</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="profile-name">Frag grenades</td>
    <td>6"</td>
    <td>Grenade D6</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>Blast.</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="profile-name">Krak grenades</td>
    <td>6"</td>
    <td>Grenade 1</td>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>-1</td>
    <td>D3</td>
    <td>-</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: So this works fine in the data listed above, but how would this scale to say, 5-10 entries? if it is at all possible to do so?

When I say entries I'm referring to if the code set was large and contain multiple of the above code.

Comment: forgive me for not knowing JS, how would this be added into a CSS external style sheet.

Comment: It cannot be executed from a stylesheet. You'd either need to inline the JS in a `<script>/*js here*/<script>` tag, or put it in an external file and reference it like this: `<script src="/path/to/my-script.js" defer></script>`.